# Github Pages and SASS - project page does not load images

Tags: url, github, hyperlink, sass

I have now spent a lot of time to figure this out, but I just can't come up with a solution. Basically a relative link like this just won't work:

```
background-image: url(../../img/footer_lodyas.png);
```

I don't know why. In my other project such relative links are working just fine. The only difference is, that here I'm using SASS/SCSS, and I don't know what to do. I already tried to use direct links to the images in the repo, but that also didn't work.

It is also strange, that the SCSS is working, so all styles etc. are there, it is just the URLs which make a problem.

I don't have a _config.yml file, since it is not neccessary anymore for having relative links - well maybe not with a css preprocessor?

Answer (score 0):

so for anyone who is having a similiar problem here is my solution:

I had the path of the URL set to the path of the SCSS-file and not to the main.css, so instead oof having

`background-image: url(../../img/footer_lodyas.png);`

which would be valid for the path of my SCSS-file I changed it to the path of my main.css. Now everything works fine on github, without even using an _config.yml file.

`background-image: url(../img/footer_lodyas.png);`

It has to be that way, because my main.css is in a folder called "css" which is in the same folder as my folder "img".